# How To get socket.io working with express-sessions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, session, socket.io

I have been trying to understand how to get sessions to work with node.js to get users to be authenticated once signed up. (will need to do the same with logging existing users eventually) However the session data doesn't seem to be staying with the user (my localhost).

So I have been reading up on several pages, trying to understand how

```
express
express-session
socket-io 
cookie-parser (not required??)
body-parser (also not required as I am getting data from client via socket-io?)
passportjs (read up on this but im not sure if this is the right way forward?)
```

Can worth together in a system to authenticate users. I thought i had it, however the

```
req.session.whatever
```

is not being carried over from one page to another.

My requires

```
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();
var serv           = require('http').Server(app);
var credential     = require('credential');
var session        = require('express-session');
var bodyParser     = require("body-parser");
var cookieParser   = require('cookie-parser');

var RPSQL = require('./mysql-all.js'); // Contains all the scripts for MYSQL
```

Any .use, .get .post to configure express.

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret : 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
}));
app.get('/client/RPGamePage.html', function(req,res){
    console.log("On Game Page");
    console.log(req.session)
    if(req.session.loggedin){
        console.log("Logged in");
    } else {
        res.redirect('/client/RPLoginPage.html');
    }

});
app.post('/authenticate',function(req,res){
    console.log("AUTENTICATE");
    req.session.loggedin = true;
    res.redirect('/client/RPGamePage.html');
    console.log(req.session)
});
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/RPHomePage.html');
    res.redirect('/client/RPHomePage.html');
    // res.redirect('/client/phpmyAdmin/index.php');
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/client',express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
serv.listen(80);
console.log("Server started.");
```

Socket.io code

```
var io = require('socket.io')(serv, {});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    // On Connection set up the listeners
    console.log("User: " + socket.id + " Connected!")
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log("User: " + socket.id + " Disconnected!")
    });

    socket.on('sendSignup',function(data){      
        // Need To Check if the username exisists in database
        RPSQL.mysql_UserExsist(data.username)           
        .then(res => res)
        .then(res => {
            RPSQL.mysql_addUser(data.username,data.password)
        })
        .then(res =>{
            socket.emit('sendSignup',"true")
        })

        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        })

    });
});
```

Code on the client.

```
var socket = io();
        $(function(){           
            $("#SignupBtn").click(function(e){              
                //User input validations before sending data.
                if($("#username").val() && $("#password").val()){
                    console.log("Signed up");
                      e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
                      data = {
                            username: $("#username").val(),
                            password: $("#password").val()            
                      }

                      socket.emit('sendSignup',data);
                      return false;
                }else {

                    console.log("Please enter all data");
                 }
                });
            socket.on('sendSignup',function(data){

                console.log(data);
                if(data === "true"){
                    $.post("/authenticate", function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    });
                } else if (data === "false") {
                    //Error
                } else {
                    //Error
                }
            })  
        })
```

The problem is when I get /authenticate to trigger and set

```
req.session.loggedin = true
```

then I either redirect or goto the /client/RPGamePage.html

```
req.session.loggedin
```

Does not exist and this the user is redirected back to the /client/RPUserPage.html

Really stock on this one, going round and round trying to figure this one.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @ItayGanor it was a long time ago, i believe i set a cookie and that was carried over.